# New column from calculating 2 other eager columns Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I get 2 numbers made through `withCount` in my Eloquent query result. Is there any way to multiply/divide/add these 2 numbers and make a new field?

```
$data = Trek::select('name')
            ->withCount('past_bookings')
            ->withCount('bookings')
            ->get();
```

(Like `->select(DB::raw('past_bookings*bookings as new_col'))`??)

When I used an accessor, I got `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on int` error.

Comment: before you run the query above enable the query log `\DB::enableQueryLog();` ... after you run that query above you can dump the query log to see what query is generated ... `dump(\DB::getQueryLog());` ... add that output to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need new column? You can do on your model;

```
protected $appends = ['my_calculation'];

public function getMyCalculationAttribute()
{
    return $this->past_bookings_count * $this->bookings_count;
}
```

you can access it like this:

```
$trekModel->my_calculation;
```

you can look [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: that would defeat the purpose of eager loading the counts, no? ... since now the entire record set for both relationships would need to be loaded

Comment: if you use


        return $this->past_bookings_count * $this->bookings_count;

like that with withcounts, no problem. I am editing the answer

Comment: Oh yes, I did think about this, but I got an error `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on int`. Is it because both of those are not present in the table but calculated eagerly?

Comment: yes bro. I tested this code that I write, and it works. there is no need foreach etc.. Call eagerly your relation counts, add these codes in your model and access it with "['my_calculation']" or "->my_calculation"

Comment: @Alper Oh, Guess some configuration is wrong on my side. I'm still getting the `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on int` using accessor.

Comment: Sorry mate, wish could help.. did you control your foreign id names? maybe you can edit your question and show us your past_bookings and bookings relations?

Comment: @Alper , dude, it worked. It needed `protected $appends = ['my_calculation'];`  for the error to go away! Did you have that already? It'll be nice if you add that too to your answer. Thanks, mate!

Comment: of course bro, cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it via another step. Like that:

```php
$collection = Trek::select('name')
            ->withCount('past_bookings')
            ->withCount('bookings')
            ->get();

$data = [];
foreach($collection as $item) {
    $data['past_bookings_count/bookings as new_col'] = ($item['past_bookings'] / $item['bookings_count']);
}


dd($data);
```

However, if this is passed on to a view, I would leave the loop and carry out the calculation in the view.

**.blade.php**

`{{ $data['past_bookings_count'] / $data['bookings_count'] }}`

Comment: you would have to do that in a loop since that is a Collection of records, not a single record

Comment: @lagbox you are right! i will update my answer.

Comment: also the attributes that have the counts will be `past_bookings_count` and `bookings_count`, that is how `withCount` names the field it adds ... what is `'past_bookings/bookings as new_col` supposed to be btw?

Comment: @lagbox i updated again. thanks for the good advice. the points are yours !

Comment: Thank you, seems like `foeach` is the only solution. :-(